# Find the values from datatable based on list

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list name `str` in which series name is stored (like `"Series 2"`,`"Series4"`) etc. and a `DataTable` named `dtSeriesData` in which values of the series are stored.

I want to fetch values from `dtSeriesData` based on series name in `str` list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to filter the table, so that you only get rows which these series? You can use LINQ:

```
var filteredRows = dtSeriesData.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => str.Contains(row.Field<string>("ColumnName")));
```

If you want a new `DataTable` with the filtered rows use `CopyToDataTable`.

You could also use `Enumerable.Join` which is more efficient. I use query syntax when it comes to join:

```
var filteredRows = from row in dtSeriesData.AsEnumerable()
                   join name in str
                   on row.Field<string>("ColumnName") equals name
                   select row;
```